# Django: Multiple menus

Tags: django, menu

My django based website will have 3 seperate menus. The items of first one are: contact, about, disclosures. The second one will have: terms and condtions, privacy policy, copyright. And items of main menu are: Home, link1, link2, link2.... The first two menus will have fixed items, and the items of last one may change. As I will be using forloop in the template, what is the best approach for creating those menus. The webpages will have just a title and content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use [inclusion template tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) for dynamic menus.

In `my-app/templatetags/myappmenu.py`, I have something like:

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()
@register.inclusion_tag('my-app/menu.html')
def myappmenu():
    return [("label1", "link1"), ("label2", "link2")]
```

Then, in your template you can loop over the items and produce the menu in the format you desire (`<p>`, `<ul>`, etc.).

If you need to make items in the menu appear conditionally, you can add them to the list by checking permissions in the template tag; just pass the request or user object as argument to the template tag function.

Comment: As a side note: this makes it really easy to define multiple menus: just make a template tag for each menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can stay **DRY** and just use **[django-menuware](https://github.com/un33k/django-menuware)**. It supports **nested menus** as well.

**Install:**

```
pip install django-menuware
# Add `menuware` to your settings.py**
# Add `MENUWARE_MENU` to your settings.py:**
```

**Settings:**

```
MENUWARE_MENU = {
    "RIGHT_NAV_MENU": [
        {   # Show `Login` to `unauthenticated` users ONLY
            "name": "Login",
            "url": "/login/",
            "render_for_unauthenticated": True,
        },
        {   # Show `Logout` to `authenticated` users ONLY
            "name": "Logout",
            "url": "/logout/",
            "render_for_authenticated": True,
        },
        {   # Show `Search` to all users
            "name": "Search",
            "url": "/search/",
            "render_for_unauthenticated": True,
            "render_for_authenticated": True,
        },
    ],
    "LEFT_NAV_MENU": [
        {   # Show `Admin` to `superuser` ONLY
            "name": "Admin",
            "url": "admin:index", # Reversible
            "render_for_authenticated": True,
            "render_for_superuser": True,
        },
       {   # Show `Comment Admin` to `staff` users ONLY
            "name": "Comment Admin",
            "url": "/review/admin/",
            "render_for_authenticated": True,
            "render_for_staff": True,
        },
    ]
```

**Usage:**

```
<!-- base.html -->
{% load menuware %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><title>Django Menuware</title></head>
    <body>
        <!-- NAV BAR Start -->
        {% get_menu "LEFT_NAV_MENU" as left_menu %}
        <div style="float:left;">
            {% for item in left_menu %}
                <li class="{% if item.selected %} active {% endif %}">
                    <a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

        {% get_menu "RIGHT_NAV_MENU" as right_menu %}
        <div style="float:right;">
            {% for item in right_menu %}
                <li class="{% if item.selected %} active {% endif %}">
                    <a href="{{item.url}}">{{item.name}}</a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <!-- NAV BAR End -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Minimally, you'd want to look at its Github [README](https://github.com/un33k/django-menuware) page before rolling your own.